# How can I set this program on PyQt 4?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, lxml

I wrote this program with python to ease modding for a game. Its purpose is to make an XML file and set up some tags. I used mostly information from this website for help and I learned of lxml in this website. 
I was hoping to find some help with making a GUI for it with PyQt4. I have looked for videos and other websites, but have not found much help. I tried some times to make a GUI for a simpler version of this program, but I kept failing to make anything that worked. Anything that could help me to get a GUI for this would surely help. The few videos I have seen on this just taught me how to make a window with a button with PyQt4. Tried making at least that but, cannot make the main class inherit from lxml.

In short, I just want help to make a GUI..just getting it set up. Any pointers or at the very least get a critique of my current code. I am new to stack overflow and if this question is poorly made please mention it to learn to ask better.

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

def askNameFeature():
    Name = input("What will be the name of your feature? ")
def askDesc(category):
    global Description
    Description = input("What will be the description of  " + category + "? ")
    return Description
def askDevTime():
    global DevTime
    DevTime = input("What will be the DevTime? ")
def askUnlockSoftware():
    au = input("What will be the year this software unlocks? ")
    global Unlock
    Unlock = int(au)

def askUnlockFeature():
    global UnlockF
    UnlockF = input("When does this feature unlock? ")
    return UnlockF
def askInnovation(category):
    global Innovation
    Innovation = input("What is the innovation of this " + category + "? ")
    return Innovation 
def askUsability():
    global Usability
    Usability = input("What is the usability of this feature? ")
    return Usability
def askStability():
    global Stability
    Stability = input("What is the stability of this feature? ")
    return Stability
def askCodeArt():
    global CodeArt
    CodeArt = input("What is the Code Art needed for this feature? ")
    return CodeArt
def askServer():
    global Server
    Server = input("What is the server need for this feature? ")
    return Server


nameChoice = input("What will you name your software? ")

Name = nameChoice

print("This file will be saved as " + nameChoice + ".xml")

Description = input("What is the description of your software? ")

Popularity = input("What will be the popularity of your software?")

Random = input("What will be the random value for this software?")

OSSpecific = input("Yes or No, is this software dependent on an Operating System?")
global numberOfFeatures
numberOfFeatures = input("How many features will this Software type have.")

numberOfFeatures = int(numberOfFeatures)
def mainFunction():
    x = numberOfFeatures
    nameChoice = Name
    root = etree.Element("SoftwareType")
    etree.SubElement(root, "Name").text = Name
    etree.SubElement(root, "Description").text = "Description"
    etree.SubElement(root, "Random").text = "Random"
    etree.SubElement(root, "Popularity").text = "Popularity"
    etree.SubElement(root, "OSSpecific").text = "OSSpecific"
    etree.SubElement(root, "OneClient").text = "False"
    etree.SubElement(root, "InHouse").text = "InHouse"
    etree.SubElement(root, "Category").text = "Category"
    etree.SubElement(root, "Unlock").text = "Unlock"
    etree.SubElement(root, "NameGenerator").text = "NameGenerator"
    etree.SubElement(root, "Needs").text = "Needs"
    features = etree.SubElement(root, "Features")

    while (x > 0):
        askNameFeature()
        askDesc(Name)
        askUnlockFeature()
        askDevTime()
        askInnovation("Function")
        askUsability()
        askStability()
        askCodeArt()
        askServer()
        feature = etree.SubElement(features, "Feature")
        etree.SubElement(feature, "Name").text = Name
        etree.SubElement(feature, "Description").text = Description
        etree.SubElement(feature, "Unlock").text = UnlockF
        etree.SubElement(feature, "DevTime").text = DevTime
        etree.SubElement(feature, "Innovation").text = Innovation
        etree.SubElement(feature, "Usability").text =Usability
        etree.SubElement(feature, "Stability").text = Stability
        etree.SubElement(feature, "CodeArt").text = CodeArt
        etree.SubElement(feature, "Server").text = Server
        #etree.SubElement(feature, "Dependencies").text = Dependencies

        x = x - 1
    print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
    text = (etree.tostring(root,pretty_print=True))
    saveFile = open(nameChoice+".xml",'wb')

    saveFile.write(text)

    saveFile.close()

mainFunction()
```

Comment: I would replace all your `input` by a form, with `QFormLayout`, `QLineEdit` and `QSpinBox`. Then your only left with one function, so you don't really need to inherits from lxml, you can put everything in one python file.

Comment: Ok, I have made my gui and it works. However, doing things in certain ways can cause errors. How do I get warning windows to open up and interact with my main window? I am using qt designer to create my GUI. I have a button that does a function. How can I make it so a pop up ok/cancel dialog opens up and the function only happens if 'ok' is pressed.